# Pattern matching in AWK

Tags: shell, awk

I have following requirement. I want to skip first and last lines in file. And in all other lines, have to check for space in first two characters. For this I am replacing spaces with some characters and extracting the first characters. I should compare them with # and throw some error if it matches

```
AWK 'NR>2 {gsub(/\ /,"#",prev);}{print substr(prev,1,2)}{prev=$0}' input file
```

With this I am able to replace and extract, but not able to compare the substring with ##. Please help

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

no need to substitute and test the substitute, instead you can do this

```
$ awk 'p~/^  /{exit 1} NR>1{p=$0}' file
```

delayed computation will skip the last record, to skip the first record condition on `NR>1`, if a record starts with two spaces exit with error code, otherwise it will exit with success (default).